Flutter GetX Obx Rebuild After Controller has beed deleted
I'm new to flutter and I'm using GetX.
My widget:
Obx(() => Radio(
              value: Get.find<BuyController>().paymentRadioList[index],
              groupValue:
                  Get.find<BuyController>().paymentRadioGroupValue.value,
              fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(theme.colorScheme.primary),
              onChanged: (value) {
                if (value == null) {
                  return;
                }
                Get.find<BuyController>().paymentRadioGroupValue.value = value;
              }))

And BuyController is initiated just here:
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    buyController = Get.put(BuyController());
  }

Once the user done the payment, I will call
Get.back();
to pop this page and go to the home page.
But I feel there is a problem that, due to the Obx widget is using Get.find(), once the page is popped, the controller is deleted and obx will try to rebuild the widget, causing LateInitializationError: Field 'vDf' has not been initialized.
Does anyone have any solution for this circumstance? Thank you.
Once the page was popped, obx shouldn't try to rebuild

I think this will do the job.

Get.put(Controller(), permanent: true);


I think it is best to initialize the controller directly inside the class rather than in the initstate method.. By doing this you will be able to automatically dispose off the controller when navigating back. Also you can use the buycontroller throughout the class rather than calling Get.find() everywhere.
